# The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: asp.net, excel, oledbconnection

I am getting below error when after uploading my asp.net application on window server 2008 R2

> The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine.

I have used oleDbConnection class as below to read excel file

```
OleDbConnection excelConn = null;

            try
            {
                if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".xlsx")
                {

                    excelConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'");
                }
                else
                {
                    excelConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'");
                }

                excelConn.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt = excelConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
```

After searching google i found that i need to install **[2007 Office System Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)**
so i have also tried that however i am getting same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yesterday, I faced same issue.

Followed below steps which solved my problem:-

1. Installed this 64-bit driver [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)
2. On application pool --> properties, Set `Enable 32 bit` to `True` and With `Classic` pool.
3. Changed `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` to "`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'`"
4. Build your project by setting `target platform` to `Any CPU`.

Answer (score 4):

I got solution from @siva and he has saved my life thanks a lot to him.

However i want to below share screen shot so exactly other can see where need to change that setting

Whatever application pool you have used for your application, select it from application pool in IIS and right click on that and open Advance setting

[image]

and follow the steps which @siva has mentioned in his answer

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine
Background

Amphis Customer is designed to work on 32 or 64 bit PCs running Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 or Windows 8 Pro, but on Windows XP 64 bit (and possibly other operating systems) it is possible that some of the Microsoft OLEDB DLLs have not been registered.

***The Solution No. 1 :p***

The solution is to manually register those DLLs.

go to Start->Run and type cmd
this starts the Command Prompt
(also available from Start->Programs->Accessories->Command Prompt)

type cd .. and press return
type cd .. and press return again (keep doing this until the prompt shows :> )

now you need to go to a special folder which might be c:\windows\system32 or it might be c:\winnt\system32 or it might be c:\windows\sysWOW64
try typing each of these eg
cd c:\windows\sysWOW64
(if it says The system cannot find the path specified, try the next one)
cd c:\windows\system32
cd c:\winnt\system32
when one of those doesn't cause an error, stop, you've found the correct folder.

now you need to register the OLE DB 4.0 DLLs by typing these commands and pressing return after each

regsvr32 Msjetoledb40.dll
regsvr32 Msjet40.dll
regsvr32 Mswstr10.dll
regsvr32 Msjter40.dll
regsvr32 Msjint40.dll

***The Solution No. 2 :p***

just right click on the project -> properties -> build -> change from target any cpu to target x86

-> f5 and it will work *